# Error mwssage of use laravel-jsvalidation plugin does not work with tinyMCE

Tags: validation, laravel-5, tinymce-4

In my Laravel 5.7 application I use laravel-jsvalidation plugin( https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/wiki/Basic-Usage )
and it worked ok, including textarea inputs, as :

```
<div class="form-row mb-3 {{ in_array('description', $errorFieldsArray) ? 'validation_error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        {{ Form::textarea('description', isset($vote->description) ? $vote->description : '', [   "class"=>"form-control editable_field textarea_input ", "rows"=>"5", "cols"=> 120, "placeholder"=>"Enter string description in 255 characters.", "id"=>"description", "autocomplete"=>"off"  ] ) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But after I added tinyMCE for textarea input I got a problem, that as description is required I do not see error message
on validation failure for textarea input.
The source of tinyMCE input is rather complicated https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9l2A.jpg
and I have no idea how to fix it.
1) If there is a way ?

2) If laravel-jsvalidation plugin has some javascript event methods, like on validation failure ? That could be useful...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When TinyMCE is injected into the page the original form element (e.g. `<textarea>`) is no longer visible.  If you use your browser tools you will see that TinyMCE injects a series of `<div>`s and an `<iframe>` effectively hiding your `<textarea>`.

Because of this, if you ask a validation tool to look at the value in the `<textarea>` it likely still has its initial value from when you first loaded TinyMCE.

In order to have your validation tool validate the underlying `<textarea>` you first have to update the `<textarea>` with the current contents of TinyMCE.  To do this you need to use TinyMCE's `triggerSave()` API.  This will force TinyMCE to immediately update the underlying `<textarea>` with the current value in the editor. At that point your validation tooling will know what content exists in the editor.